# RoundingMode.UP with DecimalFormat does not work as expected

Tags: java, double, rounding

I'm trying to round up a Double number whenever there is a decimal value. I'm trying the below.
The below snippet is rounding up all other values as expected.

```
1.08 -> 2
9.5 -> 10
```

but rounds 0.08 as 0 instead of 1. Am I missing something here?

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0");
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.UP);
Double number = 0.08;
System.out.println(df.format(number)); // expecting 1 but produces 0
    
number = 1.08;
System.out.println(df.format(number)); // correctly produces 2
```

Comment: This is not directly an answer to the question, but is there a reason you do not use [`Math.ceil(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#ceil(double))?

Comment: That is very strange. It seems that the threshold is `number = 0.10;` for rounding up. I tried `number = 0.0999999999999999;`, but it gives 0.

Comment: we have a requirement to make the rounding mode configurable based on user's input. I thought using DecimalFormat's setRoundingMode should be a better option because I can directly pass user's selection and not implement different logic for each mode. i  found this issue while testing and wanted to understand if there is something i'm missing

Comment: Report it as a bug. This cannot be the correct behavior.

Comment: *Workaround:* Use `BigDecimal.valueOf(number).setScale(0, RoundingMode.UP).toPlainString()` --- This ignores `Locale`.

Answer (score 11):

This looks like a manifestation of [bug JDK-8174722](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8174722), reported for JDK8, and still open with a fix version "tbd" (I see the same behavior on JDK14). In that bug report, rounding up `0.0001` to two fewer decimal places incorrectly results in `0.00` rather than `0.01`.

I tried to trace this calculation through the source code of `DecimalFormat` and found multiple assumptions on numbers of significant digits, retained for compatibility but apparently the cause of issues like this. My hunch based on the source code is that if the first digit after the requested precision is 0 (or close enough) the function rounds down.  This behavior is contrary to the documentation which clearly states otherwise.

If it were easy to fix, I gather the linked bug would have been fixed long before now, but it also appears to be a low priority.

As the comments have suggested, using `Math.ceil()`, `Math.floor()`, and `Math.round()` functions would provide more predictable/consistent results and suffice for most use cases.

In your comments, you suggested the user provided the `RoundingMode`, so if you want a direct application of that enum, the [bug report's MCVE](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/secure/attachment/66449/JI9047626.java) includes a workaround using `BigDecimal.setScale()`.  [@Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221149/andreas) posted an application of this workaround in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63207758/java-roundingmode-up-for-double-values-less-than-1-does-not-work-as-expected#comment111773462_63207758) to produce this string:

```
// Note: this ignores Locale
BigDecimal.valueOf(number).setScale(0, RoundingMode.UP).toPlainString();
```

Another option using a `DecimalFormat` would allow changing Locale settings and would be:

```
df.format(BigDecimal.valueOf(number).setScale(0, RoundingMode.UP));
```

Note that since you would use the rounding up in `setScale()` you do not need to also use it in the `DecimalFormat`.